# Tokyo Tyrant indexes

Tags: database, indexing, tokyo-cabinet, tokyo-tyrant

I was wondering about size requirements for Tokyo Tyrant indexes.

If I have an index on field `x` and insert a record with fields `y` and `z` only, does the `x` index grow? Also: does the insert time grow in that case?